# React custom hook to fetch document from firebase isLoading always false

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I created this custom hook to fetch (in this case listen to) a document in firestore:

```
import { doc, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { db, auth } from '../../firebase';

function useCurrentUser() {
  const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;

  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [isUserLoading, setIsUserLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isUserError, setIsUserError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      try {
        setIsUserLoading(true);
        const userRef = doc(db, 'users', userId);
        const unsub = await onSnapshot(userRef, doc => {
          setUser(doc.data());
        });
      } catch (error) {
        setIsUserError(error);
      } finally {
        setIsUserLoading(false);
      }
    };

    getUser();
  }, []);

  return { user, isUserLoading, isUserError };
}

export default useCurrentUser;
```

The problem is: `isUserLoading` is always returning `false` even though in the `try` statement, I'm setting it to `true`

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that `onSnapshot` returns a promise that you can await? It doesn't look like it would

Comment: You're right. How stupid of me. I checked the firebase docs again https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen Thanks!

Comment: Even after removing `await`, `isUserLoading` still always returns `false`

Comment: Doesn't finally always get called after try or catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSnapshot` returns a function, not a promise, so you can't `await`

So what you want to do is:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setIsUserLoading(true);
  const userRef = doc(db, 'users', userId);
  const unsub = onSnapshot(userRef, snapshot => {
    if(!snapshot.exists()) return
    setIsUserLoading(false);
    setUser(snapshot.data());
  });

  return unsub
}, []);
```

In your current code, `finally` would run immediately, because there is nothing to await for

Comment: Close, but your solution will make it false immediately too.

Comment: Thanks! Putting the `setIsUserLoading` inside the callback function worked.

Comment: I changed the initial `isUserLoading` value to `true` and I'm setting to `false` in the `unsub` per above

Comment: You should first check are data exists. Then assign data and make loading false. `onSnapshot()` is a listener it works with local storage. First it returns no data or cached data if exists and make request to database. When request get respond it triggers again.

Comment: @Mises feel free to edit my answer, I'm not an expert

Answer (score 0):

From w3schools.com:

> The try statement defines the code block to run (to try).
>
> The catch statement defines a code block to handle any error.
>
> The finally statement defines a code block to run regardless of the result.

So you're setting it to `true` in the `try` then setting it back to `false` right after.

Comment: But this is an intended behaviour that OP wanted, but the `try` block would have to wait for the data which isn't happening

Comment: Oh I see it now, you're absolutely right